# Matlab, fdesign, sample rate

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, sample-rate

I am using the function `fdesign.lowpass` in Matlab, on a signal that is sampled at 8kHz. I am making a filter for a speech signal and want to filter out gaussian noise, i have found the fundamental freq. to be around 343Hz with FFT.

So I am using the command in Matlab:

```
fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',319,378,0.25,1,8000);
```

Should my sample rate be 8000/2?

Answer (score 0):

> Should my sample rate be 8000/2?

No, the `Fs` argument should be the actual sampling rate, so in your case `8000`. The other frequency arguments would then be interpreted to be in Hz and should then be less than 8000/2 (which is what you have now).

Note also that I doubt that you only want 1dB of stopband attenuation as specified with `Ast` if you want to see any sort of significant out-of-band noise reduction. Also, you might want to increase your passband cutoff frequency (`Fp`) to actually include your signal's fundamental frequency (and perhaps a few harmonics as well, depending on your application).

Comment: ' fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',1000,1600,1,50,8000); '

Comment: ' fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',1000,1600,1,50,8000); '

Does that look better?

Comment: That's more in line with what I'd expect for a typical application.